# Integrate Stripe Checkout with Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, architecture, stripe-payments

I have an existing Rails application where users can create classifieds/ads for boats. Currently there is no payment integrated and once user submits the form, it gets posted. Now I am looking to add Spripe Checkout (as it seems the easiest, correct me if i'm wrong) to my app. I am not sure what would be the best way to approach this. Ideally I would like the user to submit the form and then be asked to pay.

Also, I am not sure which approach I should take: 1) the ad gets created in the database first and then with the payment a Boolean column value (for example "payment") gets changed or 2) the ad's database record gets created only with a successful payment.

Should I create a new Charges controller like Stripe tutorial suggests or incorporate it in my existing AdsController?

**ads_controller.rb**

```
class AdsController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:edit, :update, :new]
before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
    if params[:category].blank? && params[:state].blank?
        @ads = Ad.all.order("created_at DESC")
    elsif params[:category].blank?
        @state_id = State.find_by(name: params[:state]).id
        @ads = Ad.where(state_id: @state_id).order("created_at DESC")
    else 
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @ads = Ad.where(category_id: @category_id).order("created_at DESC")
    end
    @ads = @ads.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 21)
end

def new
    @ad = Ad.new
end

def create
    @ad = current_user.ads.build(ad_params)
    if @ad.save
        flash[:success] = "Ad successfully created"
        redirect_to @ad
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def show
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @ad = Ad.find(params[:id])
    if @ad.update_attributes(ad_params)
        flash[:success] = "Ad successfully updated"
        redirect_to @ad
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @ad.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Ad deleted"
    redirect_to request.referrer || root_url
end

private

    def ad_params
        params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :price, :year, :location, :description, :contact_name, :contact_number, :category_id, :picture, :picture2, :picture3, :state_id)
    end

    def correct_user
        @ad = current_user.ads.find_by(id: params[:id])
        redirect_to root_url if @ad.nil?
    end

    def logged_in_user
        unless logged_in?
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in"
        redirect_to login_path
        end
    end
```

my current **form**:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@ad, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

        <%= f.label "Category:" %>
        <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Select Category" }, class: 'form-control' %>

        # Lots of other form fields

        <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

    <% end %>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more railsesque to create a separate controller than build it into the ads controller.  You should definitely wrap the entire db process in what is known as a 'transaction' and look to save the add only on successful payment.  If any part fails throughout the 'transaction' process it will roll back your database and maintain conformity.

The jstripe tutorials are very in depth but if you're looking for more information and specific examples I read a great book I bought on this subject that walked me around a lot of the pitfalls and gotchas you may run into:
https://www.masteringmodernpayments.com/

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful! I ended up doing exactly what you suggested - created a separate controller for payments. I allow users to create ad first (save in db) and then ask for payment on the next page. If not paid immediately, the ad will stay in the database (but will not be listed) for a period of time and will be deleted after that. Users can manage all their ads, including payments, and have the option to pay any time. It is probably not the kind of "transaction" process you had in mind, but for this current app it works pretty well.